# How can multiple different users use the same rest api on a platform to pull their unique data?

Tags: node.js, database, api, rest, shopify

I want to build a project where a user will be able to press on a button to authorize my platform to access their data (e.g shopify data). When my platform has access (to their shopify platform) it will send that data to my database.

My questions is:

In order for my rest api to access the data (from e.g shopify platform) i have to give the rest api the api key of the user which is simple if it a single account, but when i have multiple users using the same rest api how should i handle it? How can i give the rest api the access code so it can pull the data (from e.g their shopify platform) for each user? What is the name of the technology that needs to be considered here?

I am a built lost on the terminology of my question which has given me a bit of a headache when trying to google it.

Comment: The user would have to have to create an access token in shopify and then send this access token to yoru REST API.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you create an App that Shopify approves, and then your merchant customers would install this App in their store. That approval process by both Shopify and the merchant means you are given permission to access their Shopify data.

Next, you create some value by allowing the merchant to see their data in ways unique to what it is you are doing. So far, your database contains nothing but the name of the store and the access token with permission to access the Shopify API.

How you then proceed in your own App is up to you. Not much else to it really, if you already know what your value add is. Code that part up and you're done!